# validation errors in vuejs not showing

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a SPA where I want to show validation errors on my register page.

Register.vue:

```js
export default {
    middleware: 'guest',

    data: () => ({
        errors: [],
        form: ({
            name: '',
            email: '',
            password: '',
            password_confirmation: ''
        }),
        mustVerifyEmail: false
    }),
    
    methods: {
        async register() {
            this.errors = []
            try {
                await axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie')
                let response = await axios.post('/api/register', this.form)
                console.log(response)
            } catch (error) {
                this.errors = error.response.data.errors
                console.log(this.errors.email)
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Register.vue HTML:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <input v-model="form.email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="E-Mail address">
    <span v-if="errors.email" class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        {errors.email}
    </span>
</div>
```

In my web console I get a JSON response with the errors, but the span is not showing.

Comment: Do you see any error in `console` when you do `console.log(this.errors.email)`?

Comment: Yes, it returns the error in an array ```Array [ "The email has already been taken." ]```

Comment: can we see the full component?

Comment: @mrhn added the full js

Comment: Does `VueJS` template engine allow single `{`?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm new to vue so I dont know what you're talking about, can you explain?

Comment: Do you see something like `{errors.email}` on the screen?

Comment: Nope and I just found out that even without v-if its not showing the span. Its just showing a ```<!---->```

Comment: Try `{{errors.email}}`. let me know if it works so I'll post it as answer

Comment: Does not work either, already tried. I guess it has something to do with the ```invalid-feedback``` being set to ```display: none;```

Comment: So what css do you apply on `invalid-feedback`?

Comment: Okay it did work with adding d-block to the classes. But now, the is-invalid class is not showing on the border of the textbox: ```:class="{ 'is-invalid': errors.mail }"```

Comment: `'is-invalid': errors.email.length`

Comment: okay well, my mistake. for it was a typing error. works now with "errors.email" instead of "errors.mail"

Comment: Is there a more beautiful way to show the error text instead of doing {{ errors.email[0] }}?

Comment: You should return `string` from the server but rather an array for a specific input. e.g `errors: [{email: 'email is already taken', username: 'username is required'}]`

Answer (score 0):

in my case, validation error message dont have my field. cause i use one request for two categories data and have condition on request file. according to sent data to request, it take back data of category one instead of category two. cause dont have those field then it cant display error message.